# Does anyone know a good free SHA1 hash generator?

Tags: html, javascript, hash

Does anyone know a good free SHA1 hash generator? I am trying to has some info on the client side before post it back. I need a free SHA1 hash generator.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a javascript implementation [here.](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)

Answer (score 2):

The [`sha1sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha1sum) command is included with many Linux distributions.  In CentOS 5.5, it's part of the coreutils package.

Comment: I really appreciate it but, I needed something in JavaScript which I found it.